# ASP.NET website supports multiple database support

Tags: asp.net

We are developing a asp.net web based application, so for example if I want to deploy the same web application with SQLSERVER as back end or MYSql as back end or Oracle as back end. only change in connectionstring then so how it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Always include full details clearly which could help us to give you right answers.

Developing an application for multiple back-ends is not an easy task because all RDBMS has different type of things, features so you have to analyze those things based on comparisons.

Check these

[Connecting to SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and MySQL simultaneously using ADO.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755091/connecting-to-sql-server-oracle-db2-and-mysql-simultaneously-using-ado-net?rq=1)

[C# Database abstraction for Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916425/c-sharp-database-abstraction-for-microsoft-sql-server-oracle-mysql-and-db2)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your connection string in the web.config file and comment out the one you don't want to support. Name the connection strings the same so that only uncommenting is needed.

```
<!-- USED FOR Internal SERVER
<add name="sqlConnectionString_r" connectionString="Server=192.168.1.2; uid=readUser; pwd=1234; database=TempDB" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>-->

<!-- USED FOR GODADDY SERVER-->
<add name="sqlConnectionString_r" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; uid=readUser; pwd=1234; database=TempDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Notice the provider name